# React Native - Image size for pixel density?

Tags: react-native

When a user uploads an avatar, I resize it to `100px x 100px` on the server.

I want to display that exact size and for the image to be sharp regardless of device accessing it, never blurred, but I know apple has 2x and 3x sizes as well for pixel density, which I am not sure if it will blur my image or not.

So since I don't have different devices to test this with at the moment, would I need to resize the image to 3 sizes to avoid any bluriness and serve the appropriate one based on pixel density? Like:

```
100px x 100px
200px x 200px
300px x 300px
```

If so that would be a pain, as there may be additional densities in the future unaccounted for. Or would the `100px x 100px` alone suffice and look sharp regardless of device pixel density?

Comment: good question I would also like to know the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two sets of units in react-native. Logical dimensions, and physical dimensions. Logical dimensions is used for layouts ie inside your styles. Physical dimensions is used for image sizing.

If you use the two API's Dimensions and PixelRatio you can get the physical width of the device your app is currently running on. Something like;

```
var { logicalWidth } = Dimensions.get('window');
var physicalWidth = logicalWidth * PixelRatio.get();
```

Obviously a 100px wide image is not going to look good on a modern phone if you are expecting the image to be stretched across the entire width of the display (the width of a Nexus 6 is 1440px). Given the range of dpi on todays phones, I would generate multiple versions of the same image on the server according to various pixelratio's that you choose upfront, and then only load the image needed for each device ie pass back the pixelratio of the device in the image url and interpret on the server backend.

Comment: hmmm... thanks hasseio - but if I have 3 different app defined sizes of the avatar/any uploaded image, instead of just the one `100px by 100px`, for different scene locations, that would mean I would need 9 copies on the server, 3 for each pixel density (looking at 2x and 3x only). Later if there is 4x, I'll have to reopen the original file, resave it at 4x, making 12 copies of each image of the 3 different sizes (multiplied by 2, 3, and 4). This sucks if it's the only way. I'll keep the question open for a few days, maybe someone chimes in with more info/a different solution :)

Comment: The only other way I see is to force the user to upload a vector format avatar ie svg. Probably not a good move :) In the end, pixels are pixels. If you don't have enough of them, you have to interpolate and that causes blurring. Have a look at Google's Material Icon library. Each icon comes in different 'application sizes' and each size has 5 different resolution representations. I think if there was a better/different solution, Google would have used it :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your images will be blurry on a device with high pixel density.
However, if someone uploads an avatar that is 20x20 pixels large and you stretch it to 100x100, it will be very blurry.